# How are cages in fusers protected against ion damage?

Tags: electrostatics, plasma-physics, nuclear-engineering

I have a simple question. Nuclear fusers (like the Farnsworth Hirsh design) use charged cages to accelerate deuterium ions to high enough energies to fuse and produce neutrons and energy. While these are easy to build (many high school students have built them), they don't last very long at high power in most amateur designs due to ion impacts onto the cages.

My question is, how are these cages protected in industrial fuser designs? What methods for protecting these cages against damage?

Comment: A little difficult to understand without a diagram, and I say that as an ion accelerator person. One answer is, in real accelerators the ion source is fairly low voltage (~5-50keV), and hydrogen really won't do much 'damage' at those voltages.

Comment: Where are fusors even used industrially? As far as I know, not many people take them seriously as an actual fusion energy solution.

Comment: @probably_someone: They are used industrially as neutron sources.